# Vim syntax highlighting lost on single file

Tags: vim, colors, highlighting, syntax

I have a strange thing happening on a single file. When I open the file under it's original name, the highlighting is lost (":syntax on" does nothing). But if I cp that file with another name and open it, the syntax highlighting returns. If I mv that copy back to the original file name, the highlighting is gone again.

I can't show you images (as my rep is not high enough), but I assure you if I could, you could clearly see that file a.js has no highlighting while a_copy.js does.

Comment: You can upload the screenshot on some image sharing site and add the link.

Comment: What does `:verbose set syntax?` (with the question mark as part of the command) show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You provide very little information about your environment and configuration, so I can just help you help yourself.

Compare the following options for the two different JavaScript files:

```
:verbose setlocal syntax? filetype?
```

Then check the list of `:autocmd` for any pattern that might target the problematic JavaScript file. Do you use a *local vimrc* plugin? It might affect this, too.

If all that doesn't provide a clue, capture the sequence of commands with

```
:set verbose=20 | edit a.js
```

and watch out for commands that affect `'syntax'`.

Comment: syntax=    
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/HEAD/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim    
  filetype=    
        Last set from ~/.vimviews/~=+github=+ctc_services-wrapper=+routes=+ctc_inventory.js=

Comment: So yeah, this file in particular isn't being recognized as a js file.

Comment: :set syntax=javascript did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Still strange; you should have a default detection `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js,*.javascript,*.es,*.jsx,*.json   setf javascript` that should cover `a.js`. The `.vimviews` looks somewhat suspect to me. If you can live with a workaround, a _modeline_ inside the file would probably fix this, too.

Comment: It was a sudden loss. The syntax was there and then it wasn't. So in all likelihood I had inadvertently hit the right key combo to turn the settings off on that file alone.

Comment: Thanks, this happened to me too using vim with spf13. No clue why(I did nothing, even reinstalled vim with spf13 and it happened again), the problem anyway was that filetype was lost for some reason. Fully working now!

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting any saved views (i.e. from mkview). I often have this problem if I didn't cleanly exit all my vims when I logout/shutdown. If you've set something like

`au BufWinLeave ?* mkview`

in your .vimrc as many do, you'll automatically have these views. As mentioned in the accepted answer, you can find where this file is by using:

`:verbose setlocal syntax? filetype?`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from having `syntax on` in `.vimrc`, you may also need to delete a view that has been stored for this particular file in the `.vim/view` dir:

```
$ cd ~/.vim/view

# list all files looking for your particular file
$ ls -lt # | head -10 
...

# delete that file
$ rm ...
```

Note that files in the `view/` folder will have their full path on the filesystem, with the `/` replaced by `=+`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since this has happened to me several times I thought I might as well share my solution.

As suggested, I compared the original and the copy (with colors) by:

`:verbose setlocal syntax? filetype?`

Original

```
  syntax=
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  filetype=
        Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+Thesis=+thesis.tex=
```

Copy

```
  syntax=tex
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  filetype=tex
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/autoload/dist/ft.vim`
```

The solution to this for me was to `:set filetype=tex` (or whatever file extension you're working with.) I haven't been able to track down exactly why this happens but it seems to me that it happens after deleting .swp files.